# C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK

Tags: android

I'm trying to build first Native app using SDK 12, I installed the updated SDK, ensured My NDK, build tools and CMake are updated.

Created new Android project, selected C++ native, and buid, I got this error:

> Configure project :app C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK. AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.","sources":[{}]} C/C++: Platform version '31' is beyond '30', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.

[image]

And installed SKD platform 12

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution and liked to share.
It looks the `C++ standard Toolchain default` I've is not supporting NDK31, so I selected the latest one `C++17` and my issue had been resolved.

[image]

Comment: See this to change the toolchain after the project has been created: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55588014